# JSON as data type in ASP.Net Core 3.1 controller

Tags: json, .net-core-3.1

I'm creating an Api using .Net Core 3.1 in which I need one property input as JSON in the controller, something like:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "JSONData": { "roles": ["data1", "data2"] }
}
```

so that I can define the request something like:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public JSON JSONData { get; set; }
}
```

I'm thinking of having it as a string and using Serialize/Deserialize it if we cannot have it as a "JSON" data type.
Is there a way to have a property as JSON type from both request and response?

Comment: simply use `string` for json data.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried with JsonElement and could see it works; only one issue that the property is not showing up from the swagger UI. So the request is like:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public JsonElement JSONData { get; set; }
}
```